# Error on matlab get_param

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm generating `tlc` files from a model. In a specific point I'm getting this error when calling `get_param`:

```
>> get_param('FGCS_Sim', 'TargetFcnLibHandle')
```

> ??? Error using ==> getTfl at 30 TFL: "None" cannot be found in the
>   registry.
>
> Error in ==>
>   C:\MATLAB\R2008b\toolbox\rtw\rtw\@RTW\@TargetRegistry\getTflTableList.p>getTflTableList
>   at 18
>
> ??? Target Function Library 'None' is missing or does not contain a valid TFL Table.

This error is occurring in `.p` file, so I can't see what's happening. But when I try with a different parameter name (one that does not exist), I get a "normal" error:

```
>> get_param('FGCS_Sim', 'foo_boo_bar')
```

> ??? block_diagram does not have a parameter named 'foo_boo_bar'.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

propose to first check property

```
'TargetFcnLib'
```

If that equals 'None' - you will run into the reported error...